# Get info if sObject is 'setup' object from metadata

Tags: apex, sobject, setup

I need to know if some sObject is setup object during runtime from apex code. Does anybody know how to do it? I checked the documentation on sObject class and didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking that you need to identify whether object is standard or custom?
If yes, then you can check whether your object name is suffixed with '__c' or not.

Comment: No. I mean setup or non-setup object. If I use in one transaction setup and non-setup objects with dml operations on them I get mixeddmloperation error.